# Sumo departing vehicles on wrong lane

Tags: sumo, traffic-simulation

After specifying the departLane, the vehicle still ends up on the wrong path. How do I prevent lane changing so the vehicles stay on the correct path? When the cars try to get into the other lane they hold all the other cars up.

```
<vehicle id="route_se792" type="PC" route="route_se" depart="792" departLane="0" />
```

```
<routes>
        <vType emissionClass="HBEFA3/PC" id="PC" departSpeed="max" departPos="base" />
        <vType emissionClass="HBEFA3/LDV" id="LDV" departSpeed="max" departPos="base" />
        <vType emissionClass="HBEFA3/zero" id="Zero" departSpeed="max" departPos="base" />
        <vType emissionClass="HBEFA3/HDV" id="HDV" departSpeed="max" departPos="base" />
        <vType emissionClass="HBEFA3/Coach" id="Coach" departSpeed="max" departPos="base"/>
        <vType emissionClass="HBEFA3/Bus" id="Bus" departSpeed="max" departPos="base" />


        <route id="route_ns" edges="n_t t_s"/>
        <route id="route_nw" edges="n_t t_w"/>
        <route id="route_ne" edges="n_t t_e"/>
        <route id="route_we" edges="w_t t_e"/>
        <route id="route_wn" edges="w_t t_n"/>
        <route id="route_ws" edges="w_t t_s"/>
        <route id="route_ew" edges="e_t t_w"/>
        <route id="route_en" edges="e_t t_n"/>
        <route id="route_es" edges="e_t t_s"/>
        <route id="route_sn" edges="s_t t_n"/>
        <route id="route_se" edges="s_t t_e"/>
        <route id="route_sw" edges="s_t t_w"/>
```

[image]